# Proper coloring for the Git PowerShell

Tags: powershell, color-scheme, windows-terminal

ALL,

I have installed Git for Windows and selected to use PowerShell.

However the coloring scheme was ugly. I couldn't see anything.

So I set the background to be white and I tried to set the text to be black, but failed.

The prompt and the command I type are black. However the output of, i.e. `git status` is white on white.

So, for the `Screen Text` I have all 3 set to 0, `Screen Background` all 3 set to 255, `Popup Text` all 3 are set to 0 and `Popup Background` all 3 are set to 255.

What am I missing? How can I set the command result font color to be black?

Whats weird about it that if I do `git diff` - I can see the output of the diff with proper coloring.

TIA!!

EDIT:

This is what I see on the screen: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzROu.jpg)

Any idea what colors I need to change in order to see filenames?

[image: What I see in the Git Shell]

Comment: The way to set colors in your terminal depends on your terminal app. I took a guess and changed the tag to [tag:windows-terminal] but if that's not right, use the right tag to get people familiar with whatever terminal app you're using.

Comment: @torek, it is PowerShell. And the tag indicated that.

Comment: PowerShell runs in any number of terminal emulators. For instance, you can run it in iterm2 on MacOS. The *color sequence* stuff depends on the terminal emulator, not on PowerShell.